# How to create two projects rather than two modules in the same workspace in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

Like the title saying , how can I create 2 projects in the same workspace in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Just curious, why you didn't [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) any of the answers given to any of your questions?

Answer (score 4):

Please read the [FAQ for Eclipse users](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/eclipse.html).

In IntelliJ IDEA workspace corresponds to a project. You can [add multiple modules to a project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-a-module-by-importing-existing-sources.html), but you can't have multiple IDEA projects open at the same time in the same window.

> **No workspace**
>
> The first thing you'll notice when launching IntelliJ IDEA is that it has no workspace concept. This means that you can work
> with only one project at a time. While in Eclipse you normally have a
> set of projects that may depend on each other, in IntelliJ IDEA you
> have a single project that consists of a set of modules.
>
> If you have several unrelated projects, you can open them in separate
> windows.
>
> If you still want to have several unrelated projects opened in one
> window, as a workaround you can configure them all in IntelliJ IDEA as
> modules.